# Replace mywebsite.com/wide-page/contact with mywebsite.com/contact in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, redirect

It is possible to replace the following URL:

> mywebsite.com/wide-page/contact

with

> mywebsite.com/contact

in WordPress Version 5.5.1 (with [Antreas Theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/antreas/)) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me:

1. I changed the Page Template to *Default*
2. Parent page to *No Parent*
3. Sidebar position to Full

After setting the above, the /wide-page/ part disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a DNS question? Does your website resolve at  http://www.mywebsite.com, and you are happy with that, but you have a page that is  http://www.mywebsite.com/wide-page/contact that you want to be http://www.mywebsite.com/contact? Or do you just want the whole site to resolve at http://www.mywebsite.com/contact?

Is it a page? or a post?

Under the title of your page or post - look for Permalink and try changing it there.

Comment: I have created a page "  — Contact", but the URL of this page is mywebsite.com/wide-page/contact and i would like to be mywebsite.com/contact.

Comment: I can only change the URL SLUG, that changes the last part of the URL. I can't delete the "wide-page" part.